# Verification of quicksort

Tags: dafny

I am trying to learn some dafny by re-implementing some C algorithms. I have a quicksort that I implemented.

```
method partition(arr: array<int>, lower: int, upper: int) returns (x: int)
  modifies a
{
    x := lower ;
   
    //Verification error: Index out of bounds
    var pivot : int := arr[upper]; 

    var j:= lower;
    while j < upper
    {
        //Verification error on arr[j]: index out of bounds
        if arr[j] <= pivot 
        {
            x := x + 1;
            arr[x], arr[j] := arr[j], arr[x]; 
        }  
        j := j + 1; 
    }

    arr[x], arr[upper] := arr[upper], arr[x];
    
    return x;
}

method quicksort(arr: array<int>, lower: int, upper: int)
{
    if upper > lower 
    {
        var partitionIndex: int := partition(arr, lower, upper);
        
        //Verification Error: decreases expression at index 2 must be bounded below by 0
        quicksort(arr, lower, partitionIndex - 1); 

        //Verification Error: decreases expression at index 1 must be bounded below by 0
        quicksort(arr, partitionIndex + 1, upper); 
    }
}
```

I tried to comment the verification errors I have received:

First for the index out of bounds errors, would I just need to prove that arr has lower and upper within its bounds? I was assuming a `requires lower <= upper <= arr.Length`. I tried this and it doesn't really solve the verification errors.

The others I received were the termination on the recursion of quicksort, I am not sure how to go about supplying a decrease for this. Would it have to be based on the partition method?

There are more verification errors but I was trying to tackle one at a time.

Comment: have you tried `upper < arr.Length` ? indexes are 0 indexed, length isn't. For an array of, say length 3, maximum index will be 2

Answer (score 1):

In Dafny proving anything about mutable data structures is really unintuitive for a beginner. Learning about twostate lemmas, the old() operator, and also well-founded orders will be needed to prove this algorithm.

There is a very useful blog post on the dafny blog about proving [Insertion sort.](https://dafny.org/blog/2023/10/11/insertion-sort/)

Chapter 15 of Program Proofs by Leino also has an implementation and proof of Quicksort.

Comment: yeah that sounds more complicated then I thought, would you recommend a different avenue? I am waiting on the book Program Proofs was excited about it when I hea

Comment: Here is a copy of the mutable quicksort. https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/ProgramProofs/ch15.dfy
And a functional version:
https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/FunctionalAlgorithms/quicksort.dfy

Comment: Generally, proving methods should go like this. You define a function using immutable data structures, then show that the method is inductively equivalent to the function. You can write lemmas about functions, but you can't for methods. I reccomend verifying smaller problems with functions and immutable datatstructures first. https://dev.to/hath995/dafny-programming-language-and-software-verification-system-2afi

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first error:

```
method partition(arr: array<int>, lower: int, upper: int) returns (x: int)
  modifies a
{
    x := lower ;
    //Verification error: Index out of bounds
    var pivot : int := arr[upper];
```

(Side note: `modifies a` should be `modified arr`.)

The problem is that `partition` is missing `requires` clauses (preconditions) to constrain the values that are allowed to be passed in. By default, any type-correct value is allowed. But if the user passes in an `int` for `upper` that is less than 0 or bigger than the length of `arr`, then that is a compile-time error. (In some other languages, that would be a run-time exception or undefined behavior, but in Dafny, it is more like a type error. You must fix it before you can run your program.)

So you, the designer of this code, need to decide what the proper precondition for `partition` is. What do you think?

Comment: `modifies a` was a typing error thank you. Let me see if I get it, lower and upper are going to be used for indexing. This means I would need the following precondition. 

`requires 0 <= lower < upper < arr.Length`

This helps solve the partition method but I do get another error in the quicksort method:

`quicksort(arr, lower, partitionIndex - 1);  //lower <= upper can't be proved`

I believe this is due to needing to prove that paritionIndex will be greater than lower, is that a correct assumption?